# Sorting an Array by Age

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

My function is sorting a Array by age, but its not working for some reason?

Other code so you know what im calling, array name etc.

```
var employeeA = new Array();
var employee = new Object();
var employeeList = [];
var employeeListA = [];
var name;
var age;
var position;
var type = 3;
var canvas;
var ctx;

function setupCanvas() {
    //alert("1");
    canvas = document.getElementById("employeeRecords");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

Heres the Sort Age code:

```
function sortAge() {
    type = 1;
    employeeList.forEach(function(empl) {
        name = empl.name;
        age = empl.age;
        position = empl.position;
        employeeA = new Array(age, name, position);
        employeeListA.push(employeeA);
    });
    var y = employeeListA.length;
    if (y > 1) {
        employeeListA.sort();
    }
}
```

this code is being called for the sorting buttons

```
function arrayButtons() {
    employeeListA = [];
    if (type === 0) {
        sortName();
    } else {

        if (type === 1) {
            sortAge();
        } else {
            employeeList.forEach(function(empl) {
                name = empl.name;
                age = empl.age;
                position = empl.position;
                employeeA = new Array(name, age, position);
                employeeListA.push(employeeA);

            });
```

Thanks for the help! Appreciate it
:D

Comment: The `.sort()` method can be passed a callback function, and that would allow you to compare parts of the array elements directly.

Comment: You can provide a sorting function to `.sort()`. Try `employeeList.sort(function( a, b ){ return a.age - b.age; });` So no need to create new arrays just to be able to use `.sort()` directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Using [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method is very easy way to get expected result in a single line of code.

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
const myTeam = [
  {
    name: "Virat",
    age: 40
  },
    {
    name: "Rohit",
    age: 30
  },
    {
    name: "Bhuvi",
    age: 20
  },
    {
    name: "Raina",
    age: 33
  }
]

const sortedByAge = myTeam.sort((firstEl,secondEl)=> secondEl.age - secondEl.age);

  console.log(sortedByAge);
```

Comment: Please relate your answer to the existing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:
[Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

TLDR:
You can use the method [`.sort`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) of an array which can take as a first argument a comparator function. This function takes 2 arguments which will be each object in the for loop.

```js
var employees = [
  {
    age: 28
  },
  {
    age: 18
  },
  {
    age: 35
  }
];
employees.sort(
    function(a, b) {
       return a.age - b.age
    }
);
console.log(employees)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I can't figure out why this works in the code snippet and Chrome console, but not in IE console. I would expect this to not work all the time, since `.sort()` expects a number and you return true or false, which is converted to 0 or 1. But if I paste this code into IE console, the array stays in the same order.

Comment: Yeah you're right, in fact, sort expects  `-1, 0 or 1` but true (1) and false (0) are enough to sort a list. Haven't tried in IE tbh, I'm only using chrome. But isn't that implicit conversion equivalent in every explorer?

Comment: In W3Schools doesn't even mention about the 3 possible values, but yes in mozilla's docs [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Comment: I think IE might not do the conversion automatically and hence, not do the sort, since true is not a number. Hence I always use + and - in sorting functions. Sidenote: it does not have to be -1 0 or 1, any number will suffice according to the spec.

Comment: It should be `a.age - b.age` and not `a.age > b.age`

Comment: You are both right. I've already edited the answer. Thank you.